# ERROR: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2010, iisreset

I get this error after having edited a few pages in SharePoint.  I have to do an IISReset on both front ends to get this to resolve.  I don't know how to fix it or even what else to supply here, but please let me know as the resets now happen several times per day.

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        ASP.NET 2.0.50727.0
Date:          1/26/2011 11:12:48 AM
Event ID:      1309
Task Category: Web Event
Level:         Warning
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      PINTSPSFE02.samcstl.org
Description:
Event code: 3005 Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. Event time: 1/26/2011 11:12:48 AM Event time (UTC): 1/26/2011 5:12:48 PM Event ID: c52fb336b7f147a3913fff3617a99d57 Event sequence: 4965 Event occurrence: 2178 Event detail code: 0  Application information:     Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1449762715/ROOT-2-129405348166941887     Trust level: WSS_Minimal     Application Virtual Path: /     Application Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80\     Machine name: PINTSPSFE02  Process information:     Process ID: 5928     Process name: w3wp.exe     Account name: SAMC\MossAppPool  Exception information:     Exception type: AccessViolationException     Exception message: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.  Request information:     Request URL: http://mosscluster/Pages/Home.aspx     Request path: /Pages/Home.aspx     User host address: 10.3.60.26     User: SAMC\BARNMD     Is authenticated: True     Authentication Type: NTLM     Thread account name: SAMC\MossAppPool  Thread information:     Thread ID: 110     Thread account name: SAMC\MossAppPool     Is impersonating: False     Stack trace:    at Microsoft.Office.Server.ObjectCache.SPCache.MossObjectCache_Tracked.Delete(String key, Boolean recursive, DeletionReason reason)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.ObjectCache.SPCache.MossObjectCache_Tracked.Get(String key)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.ObjectCache.SPCache.Get(String objectTypeName, String id)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileServiceProxy.GetPartitionPropertiesCache(Guid applicationID)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_PartitionPropertiesCache()
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.DataCache.get_PartitionProperties()
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.GetMySitePortalUrl(SPUrlZone zone, Guid partitionID)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.GetMySitePortalUrl(SPUrlZone zone, SPServiceContext serviceContext)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls.MyLinksRibbon.EnsureMySiteUrls()
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls.MyLinksRibbon.get_PortalMySiteUrlAvailable()
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls.MyLinksRibbon.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
  Custom event details: 
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="ASP.NET 2.0.50727.0" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="32768">1309</EventID>
    <Level>3</Level>
    <Task>3</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2011-01-26T17:12:48.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>35834</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>PINTSPSFE02.samcstl.org</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>3005</Data>
    <Data>An unhandled exception has occurred.</Data>
    <Data>1/26/2011 11:12:48 AM</Data>
    <Data>1/26/2011 5:12:48 PM</Data>
    <Data>c52fb336b7f147a3913fff3617a99d57</Data>
    <Data>4965</Data>
    <Data>2178</Data>
    <Data>0</Data>
    <Data>/LM/W3SVC/1449762715/ROOT-2-129405348166941887</Data>
    <Data>WSS_Minimal</Data>
    <Data>/</Data>
    <Data>C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80\</Data>
    <Data>PINTSPSFE02</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>5928</Data>
    <Data>w3wp.exe</Data>
    <Data>SAMC\MossAppPool</Data>
    <Data>AccessViolationException</Data>
    <Data></Data>
    <Data>http://mosscluster/Pages/Home.aspx</Data>
    <Data>/Pages/Home.aspx</Data>
    <Data>10.3.60.26</Data>
    <Data>SAMC\BARNMD</Data>
    <Data>True</Data>
    <Data>NTLM</Data>
    <Data>SAMC\MossAppPool</Data>
    <Data>110</Data>
    <Data>SAMC\MossAppPool</Data>
    <Data>False</Data>
    <Data>   at Microsoft.Office.Server.ObjectCache.SPCache.MossObjectCache_Tracked.Delete(String key, Boolean recursive, DeletionReason reason)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.ObjectCache.SPCache.MossObjectCache_Tracked.Get(String key)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.ObjectCache.SPCache.Get(String objectTypeName, String id)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileServiceProxy.GetPartitionPropertiesCache(Guid applicationID)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_PartitionPropertiesCache()
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.DataCache.get_PartitionProperties()
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.GetMySitePortalUrl(SPUrlZone zone, Guid partitionID)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.GetMySitePortalUrl(SPUrlZone zone, SPServiceContext serviceContext)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls.MyLinksRibbon.EnsureMySiteUrls()
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls.MyLinksRibbon.get_PortalMySiteUrlAvailable()
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls.MyLinksRibbon.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Answer (score 0):

Several things I would do:

1. run a memory scanner to do a full test on the memory modules themselves.  You might have a bad stick of ram in the server.
2. Verify all patches are applied
3. Move this to serverfault.com